# Tkinter - Button created on wrong screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create multiple windows using tkinter , but i am having no success so far ... When i create a child window and put a button on it , the button is created in the parent window!

```
from tkinter import *

class Login_screen(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.button1 = Button(text = "Open",command = lambda: self.open_login())
        self.button1.grid()

    def open_login(self):
        self.root2 = Toplevel()
        self.root2.geometry("400x200")
        self.app2 = Main_screen(self.root2)

class Main_screen(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.button = Button(text = "Close",command = lambda: self.close_windows())
        self.button.grid()

    def close_windows(self):
        self.grid_forget()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Login_screen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply the `Button()` with the master argument:

```
self.button = Button(master = self, text = "Close",command = lambda: self.close_windows())
```

`master` is the first arg to a widget so it can also be done via: `Button(self, text=...)`

This is good practice and you should get in the habit of always explicitly providing `master`, otherwise Tk defaults this arg to `None` and will place it on the root window.